# undefined reference to `readIntInRange` when compilling project with two static libraries where one library is used in the other

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compiler-errors, undefined-reference

I have a C project that has this structure:

[image]

The `main.c` has this at the top of the file:

```
#include "libbattleship/libbattleship.h"

int main()
{
    ...
```

So I include the headers in `libbattleship.h`.

`libbattleship.h` contains the prototypes of the functions of the battleship library and other type definitions. This file also includes `libinput.h` like this:

```
// DYNAMIC INCLUDES
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// STATIC INCLUDES
#include "../libinput/libinput.h"
...
```

`libinput.h` contains the prototypes for input functions. Those functions are used in the `libbattleship.c` file. This is the content of the file `libinput.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/**
 * Pauses the code
 */
void pauseExecution();

/**
 * Tries to read an int from the user input until it achieves it.
*/
int readInt(unsigned int maximum_characters_accepted);

/**
 * Tries to read an integer in a given range from user input until the range is satisfied.
 * The range goes from the minimum number to the maximum number including both of them.
*/
int readIntInRange(int minimumNumber, int maximumRange, unsigned int maximum_characters_accepted);
```

The `libinput.c` contains the implementation of the prototyped functions in `libinput.h`.

So, what I do with the two makefiles in the `libbattleship` and `libinput` is compile the library C code and package it using the `ar` utility. Here I leave the makefile of the libinput library, which is actually the library that is having the error:

```
# Compiler
CC = gcc
# Compiler flags:
# Optimization level = 3, show warnings, show extra warnings, compile with debugger symbols, link math library, Used to
# link libraries, C standard = 1999, link against libc
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -Wextra -g -lm -fPIC -std=c99 -lc
# Compiler flags for libs:
# Marks the output as shared library so we do not fail without a main, -Wl set of parameters separated by ','. The only
# parameter is -soname, which allows to mark the library with a SO_tag
CFLAGS_LIB = -shared -Wl,-soname,

# change these to proper directories where each file should be
OBJ_DIR = ../../obj
BIN_DIR = ../../bin
LIB_DIR = ../../lib

# Battleship library
$(LIB_DIR)/libinput.a : $(OBJ_DIR)/libinput.o
    mkdir -p $(LIB_DIR)
    ar -cvq $(LIB_DIR)/libinput.a $(OBJ_DIR)/libinput.o

# Battleship object
$(OBJ_DIR)/libinput.o : libinput.c
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJ_DIR)/libinput.o -c libinput.c

# Clean compilation objects
.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)/libinput.o $(LIB_DIR)/libinput.a
```

Here is the main `makefile` that calls the other two as a dependency to obtain the libraries:

```
# Compiler
CC = gcc
# Compiler flags:
# Optimization level = 3, show warnings, show extra warnings, compile with debugger symbols, link math library, Used to
# link libraries, C standard = 1999, link against libc
CFLAGS = -O3 -Wall -Wextra -g -lm -fPIC -std=c99 -lc
# Compiler flags for libs:
# Marks the output as shared library so we do not fail without a main, -Wl set of parameters separated by ','. The only
# parameter is -soname, which allows to mark the library with a SO_tag
CFLAGS_LIB = -shared #-Wl,-soname,

# change these to proper directories where each file should be
OBJ_DIR = ../obj
BIN_DIR = ../bin
LIB_DIR = ../lib

# Path to the libraries used
BATTLESHIP_LIB=$(LIB_DIR)/libbattleship.a
BATTLESHIP_LIB_DIR=libbattleship
INPUT_LIB=$(LIB_DIR)/libinput.a
INPUT_LIB_DIR=libinput

# Main target
all : $(BIN_DIR)/Battleship

# Input library
$(INPUT_LIB) : $(INPUT_LIB_DIR)/libinput.c $(INPUT_LIB_DIR)/libinput.h
    cd $(INPUT_LIB_DIR); make

# Battleship library
$(BATTLESHIP_LIB) : $(BATTLESHIP_LIB_DIR)/libbattleship.c $(BATTLESHIP_LIB_DIR)/libbattleship.h
    cd $(BATTLESHIP_LIB_DIR); make

$(OBJ_DIR)/main.o : main.c
    mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o -c main.c

# Battleship binary
$(BIN_DIR)/Battleship : $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o $(BATTLESHIP_LIB) $(INPUT_LIB)
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -static -o $(BIN_DIR)/Battleship $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o $(INPUT_LIB) $(BATTLESHIP_LIB)
    chmod 111 $(BIN_DIR)/Battleship

# Run Battleship binary
run : $(BIN_DIR)/Battleship
    $(BIN_DIR)/Battleship

# Debug Battleship binary
debug : $(BIN_DIR)/Battleship
    gdb $(BIN_DIR)/Battleship

# Clean compilation objects
.PHONY : clean
clean :
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR) $(BIN_DIR) $(LIB_DIR)
```

The problem is that when I compile the code issuing `make` I see this output:

```
mkdir -p ../obj
gcc -O3 -Wall -Wextra -g -lm -fPIC -std=c99 -lc -o ../obj/main.o -c main.c
cd libbattleship; make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/aleixmt/Desktop/Battleship/src/libbattleship'
mkdir -p ../../obj
gcc -O3 -Wall -Wextra -g -lm -fPIC -std=c99 -lc -o ../../obj/libbattleship.o -c libbattleship.c
mkdir -p ../../lib
ar -cvq ../../lib/libbattleship.a ../../obj/libbattleship.o
a - ../../obj/libbattleship.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/aleixmt/Desktop/Battleship/src/libbattleship'
cd libinput; make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/aleixmt/Desktop/Battleship/src/libinput'
mkdir -p ../../obj
gcc -O3 -Wall -Wextra -g -lm -fPIC -std=c99 -lc -o ../../obj/libinput.o -c libinput.c
mkdir -p ../../lib
ar -cvq ../../lib/libinput.a ../../obj/libinput.o
a - ../../obj/libinput.o
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/aleixmt/Desktop/Battleship/src/libinput'
mkdir -p ../bin
gcc -O3 -Wall -Wextra -g -lm -fPIC -std=c99 -lc -static -o ../bin/Battleship ../obj/main.o ../lib/libinput.a ../lib/libbattleship.a
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libbattleship.a(libbattleship.o): in function `playZero':
/home/aleixmt/Desktop/Battleship/src/libbattleship/libbattleship.c:733: undefined reference to `pauseExecution'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/aleixmt/Desktop/Battleship/src/libbattleship/libbattleship.c:734: undefined reference to `readInt'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/aleixmt/Desktop/Battleship/src/libbattleship/libbattleship.c:735: undefined reference to `readIntInRange'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/aleixmt/Desktop/Battleship/src/libbattleship/libbattleship.c:742: undefined reference to `pauseExecution'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libbattleship.a(libbattleship.o): in function `playOne':
/home/aleixmt/Desktop/Battleship/src/libbattleship/libbattleship.c:795: undefined reference to `readIntInRange'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/aleixmt/Desktop/Battleship/src/libbattleship/libbattleship.c:799: undefined reference to `readIntInRange'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libbattleship.a(libbattleship.o): in function `readMenuEntry':
/home/aleixmt/Desktop/Battleship/src/libbattleship/libbattleship.c:640: undefined reference to `readIntInRange'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libbattleship.a(libbattleship.o): in function `inputBoardDimension':
/home/aleixmt/Desktop/Battleship/src/libbattleship/libbattleship.c:647: undefined reference to `readIntInRange'
/usr/bin/ld: ../lib/libbattleship.a(libbattleship.o): in function `inputPlayerAmount':
/home/aleixmt/Desktop/Battleship/src/libbattleship/libbattleship.c:654: undefined reference to `readIntInRange'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:41: ../bin/Battleship] Error 1
```

It says that the `readIntInRange`, `readInt` and `pauseExecution` functions are undefined, but they are actually defined.

The code was working before, and I am starting to think that it is a typo.

It also it could be related to the fact that the `libinput` library is a library for the library `libbattleship`, which finally is the actual library linked with `main.o` but I am not sure how to express that with my `makefile`s and `include` directives.

If you want, you can clone the repository or see the full code of the project in [here](https://github.com/AleixMT/Battleship).

Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Okay, I have done it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -static -o $(BIN_DIR)/Battleship $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o $(INPUT_LIB) $(BATTLESHIP_LIB)
```

to:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -static -o $(BIN_DIR)/Battleship $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o $(BATTLESHIP_LIB) $(INPUT_LIB)
```

The linker processes files from left to right. When it is processing a library, it does not memorize the library and later take modules from it. It takes a module from the library if and only if it is needed when the linker processes it. That is, the linker keeps a list of symbols that are used by the executable it is building but not yet defined. If a library module defines such a symbol, the linker includes it. Otherwise, it does not.

By listing the battleship library last, none of its modules are processed before the input library, so the linker does not know the battleship library modules need symbols from the input library. So it does not take those modules from the input library.

Listing the input library last fixes that.

Comment: I should have asked before! Thank you so much!!!